# Ember Routing: Reusing a resource under multiple parent routes

Tags: ember.js

I have the following routing setup:

```
this.resource('blog',function(){
    this.resource('selectimage',{path:"selectimage/:returncontext"},function(){});
});

this.resource('post',{path:":post_id"},function(){
    this.resource('selectimage',{path:"selectimage/:returncontext"},function(){});
});
```

What I would have expected is, when navigating to blog.selectimage and post.selectimage, that the same router,controller and view would be used.
Unfortunately it seems that the last entry wins.

Is it possible to achievie this, without leaving the parent context(post/blog), when navigating to selectimage
(Obviously I could inherit from the base-selectimages-classes, but I'm hoping there is some generic ember way of doing this.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot have same resource name for two different routes as Ember relies more on naming conventions. But Ember provides ways to reuse the same controller and templates

Rename your selectimage under post to something else

```
this.resource('post',{path:":post_id"},function(){
   this.resource('xxx',{path:"xxx/:returncontext"});
});
```

And in the router, you could specify the `templateName` and `controller` that has to be reused. Something like this should make it reusable

```
App.xxxRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  controllerName: 'selectimage',
  templateName: 'selectimage'
});
```

Sample [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/selvaG/EXyr2/1/)

Comment: Nice. I wasn't aware you could specify the controller and template like that in the Route.

Comment: .. just checked the docs @ http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html: controllerName and templateName aren't mentioned.  Looking into the render method in the source code, I see that you can also specify the viewName.

Comment: Happy that helped you :) Ember Docs is getting better and better. Believe it will at its best sooner