# Item modal interface

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a list of items and want to render the item template in a modal interface.

Requirements:

- the URL should update (and hence I should use a Route)
- the existing list of items should still be shown in the background (hence the modal interface)

However when using a route the last used route is automatically closed.

Note that there are 6 routes which all show a list of items.
Making the item route a child of all these routes would be a bit cumbersome.

So far I've read through these API docs, without finding what I'm looking for:

- http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html
- http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/
- http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Location.html
- http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/

If you dont know the answer, but have good links to share, please do

Possible solution

- On IRC it was suggested to simply render a modal using the render call (see the above link). However how can I change the URL in ember without it triggering a DOM update? (related question, [Change the URL without triggering a DOM update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273323/ember-change-url))

Answer (score 0):

This is a rough example of showing a list of items and the selected item on a modal.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hesubejamayo/1/edit

In combination with the following post i think you may achieve what you are looking for.

[Ember Routing: Reusing a resource under multiple parent routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975055/ember-routing-reusing-a-resource-under-multiple-parent-routes)

Comment: Thank you so much for the example. It clarifies a lot.

Do you think there is a way to do this without ending up with multiple urls?

IE:
/recent/items/10/
/popular/items/10/

Comment: @Thierry if you need different URLs, then it is required to have multiple routes.

Comment: The goal is to have on URL for the item.
So for instance /items/10

However there are multiple pages which list items (for instance popular, recent, etc)
If I use route nesting I'll end up with multiple urls. (one for each nested route)