# Change the URL without triggering a DOM update

Tags: javascript, ember.js

How can I change the URL in ember without triggering a DOM update.
IE something like

```
window.location.hash = '/items/20';
```

However without triggering Embers routing system and the resulting DOM changes.
Note I'm currently using the hashlocation but intend to switch to history location

Background reading

- http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Location.html
- http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.HashLocation.html
- Why I want to do this in the first place ([Item modal interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25264629/item-modal-interface))

Comment: IMHO, this clearly falls into the category of "swimming against the current" when it comes to Ember.  Lots of folks use modals with Ember without jumping through hoops.

Comment: Yes its not my preferred solution, Unfortunately I haven't been able to find another workaround. See this question for more details:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25264629/item-modal-interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this took a lot of digging through the source, but here goes:

```
EmberApp.Router.router.updateURL('/item/10')
```